# Ordered Linked list.Multiple condition in while loop gives an error

Tags: python, data-structures, singly-linked-list

```
class Node:
def __init__(self,data):
    self.data=data
    self.link=None

class UnOrdered:
    def __init__(self):
        self.head=None

    def add(self,data):
        new=Node(data)
        ptr=self.head

        if self.head==None:
            self.head=new

        else:
            temp=ptr
            while ptr!=None:  #I want to write "while ptr!=None or 
                               #ptr.data<new.data"
                temp=ptr
                ptr=ptr.link
            p=temp.link
            temp.link=new
            new.link=p
    def show(self):
        if self.head==None:
            print("No nodes")
        else:
            q=self.head
            while q!=None:

                print(q.data, end=" ")
                q=q.link

ul=UnOrdered()
ul.add(3)
ul.add(5)
ul.add(4)
ul.add(11)
ul.add(10)
ul.add(5)
ul.show()
```

I am trying to create a program for ordered linked lists and for that I need to write multiple conditions in the while loop described in the "add" method.
But using multiple conditions would give me the following error:
**while ptr!=None or ptr.data
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'data'**

Comment: @Christian Dean But as soon as I inserted 3 using the add function my self.head was pointing to the new node created and was not None anymore.Correct me if I'm wrong?

Comment: Your right. I made a mistake. What your _actual_ problem is, is that you are using `or` in your `while` loop. That means regardless of whether or not your test failed(`ptr!=None`) the second part of your while statement would run(`ptr.data < new.data`). You need to use `and` instead, so you only try to accesses `data` from `ptr` if your test succeeds(eg. you know `ptr` is not `None`). As a side note, use `is` and `is not` instead of `==` and `!=` when testing with boolean and none-type values.

Comment: Please copy-paste your error.

Answer (score 1):

The reason this is happening is because of how the expression `ptr!=None or ptr.data < new.data` is evaluated.

First it will check if `ptr!=None`. If it is None (ie. the expression evaluates to False), then it will move on to the other side of the `or` and evaluate `ptr.data < new.data`. Since we already know that it is None, it tries to access the `data` attribute of `None`, and crashes.

Unfortunately this means that the expression you want to use in the `while` condition is impossible.
You will need to use a different expression - something like `while ptr!=None and ptr.data < new.data` would be valid, since if `ptr` is ever None, the expression will shortcircuit and never try evaluating `ptr.data`.